# Error when including Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

The programme compiles perfectly when:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{./include/subBookgrsrevised2018}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

However once the `\bibliography{./include/subBookgrsrevised2018}` is added I get the following:

> ! Argument of \year@short has an extra }.
>
> \par
> l.19 }

The .bib is:

```
@misc{ab,
title ="{P}rocess Control Instruction PID",
author = "{A}lan {B}radley {USA}",
note ="Instruction Set Reference",
year ="(circa 1990)",
}

@manual{al50,
title ="{C}haract.curves {NTT} 50-160/01",
author = "{A}llweiler{AG}",
edition ="V2.06, Curve number 050 01160 0129",
note ="Aust Agent Pump Power Aust Pty Ltd, email Nov 14, 2014",
address ="Melbourne, Australia",
year ="2014",
}

@manual{al77,
title ="{V}olute {C}asing {C}entrifugal {P}umps {PN}16 for {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}ils up to 350 deg {C}",
Author ="{A}llweiler {AG}",
address ={Radolfzell, Germany},
edition ="VM 500 GB/09.04 Ident No. 795277",
year ="2009",
}

@misc{audesk,
author ="{A}utodesk Inc.",
title ="{A}utocad CAD Software",
Note ="http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad/overview",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{blzpid,
author = "{B}aelz {A}utomatic",
title ="{O}perating {I}nstructions",
note = "Model 6590",
Year ="2010",
}

@misc{caht12,
author = "{C}astrol",
title ="{P}erfecto HT12 {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il ",
Note ="http://yairerez.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/PERFECTO-HT.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{dowthm,
author = {{D}ow Chemical Company},
title ="{D}owtherm Heat Transfer Fluids",
Note ="http://www.dow.com/heattrans/products/synthetic/dowtherm.htm",
Year ="(accessed October 18 2016)",
}

@misc{eath66,
author = {{E}astman Chemical Company},
title ="{T}herminol 66 Heat Transfer Fluid",
Note ="https://www.therminol.com/products/Therminol-66",
Year ="(accessed October 12 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxbe,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{B}oiler {E}fficiency",
Year ="(accessed June 2016)",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com",
}

@misc{engtboxnpsh,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{Net} {P}ositive {S}uction {H}ead",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/npsh-net-positive-suction-head-d-634.html ",
Year ="(accessed Sep 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxpid,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontrol {T}erms",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/process-control-terms-d-666.html",
Year ="(accessed Nov 2016)",
}

@misc{engtbox2,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{V}alves {F}low {C}haracteristics",
note ="https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/control-valves-flow-characteristics-d-485.html",
Year ="(accessed Oct 2021)",
}

@manual{fictrl,
author = "{F}isher {C}ontrols {I}nternalional {I}nc",
title ="{F}isher {S}izing {M}anual",
date ="April 89",
address ="USA",
year ="1989",
}

@misc{foxb,
title ="{I}ntroduction to {P}rocess {C}ontrol",
author = "{F}oxboro {MA}, {USA}",
note ="ITCG",
year ="(circa 1985)",
}

@misc{gkss,
author = "{GKSS Industrial Heating}",
title ="{G}KSS {I}ndustrial {H}eating, general information",
Note ="from {G}KSS now Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd",
Year ="2013",
}

@misc{hazardsxxI,
title ="{S}afety in Design of ThermalFluid Heat Transfer Systems",
author = {{T}ony {E}nnis},
note ="Symposium Series 155 Hazards XXI 2009 IChemE",
year ="2009",
}

@misc{hazardsxxII,
title ="{F}ire and explosion hazards with thermal fluid systems",
author = "{A}lisom McKay Projen plc UK  and {R}ichard Bradley Heat Transfer systems {UK}",
note ="Symposium Series 156 hazards XXII 2011 IChemE",
year ="2011",
}

@manual{heattl,
author = "{W}alter{W}agner",
title ="{H}eat {T}ransfer {T}echnique with {O}rganic {M}edia",
date ="3rd {E}dition, {D}ecember 1975",
address ="{S}chwetzingen {G}ermany",
year ="1977",
}

@misc{hwell,
author = "{H}oneywell",
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontroller {P}roduct {M}anual, {UDC3300}",
year ="(accessed November 16 2016)",
note = "https://www.honeywellprocess.com/library/support/Public/Documents/51-52-25-86.pdf",
}

@misc{idc,
author = "{I}ndustrial {D}ata {C}ommunications {P}ty {L}td",
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontrol {T}heory",
note ="2.01, Practical Process Control for Engineers and Technicians",
year ="1995",
}

@manual{kern,
title ="{P}rocess {H}eat {T}ransfer",
author ="{K}ern, D.Q.",
edition ="{I}nternational {S}tudent {E}dition",
note ="ISBN 0-07-Y85353-3",
address ="McGraw Hill, Singapore",
year ="1986",
}

@misc{kf21d,
author ="{K}laus Fischer",
title ="{D}ifferential Pressure Switch type 21D",
Note ="http://www.dartinstruments.com.au/images/transswi/fischer/DS21-english-alt.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{kopr,
author = "{J}etlube Co",
title ="{K}opr-Kote Anti Seize Compound",
Note ="http://www.jetlube.com/pdf/KOPR-KOTE-INDUSTRIAL-tds.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{mcad,
author = {{H}erne Software},
title ="{M}athcad",
Note ="www.hearne.software/mathcad",
Year ="(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{mobil600,
author = {{E}xon Mobil},
title ="{M}obiltherm 600 Series {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}ils",
Note ="https://lubes.exxonmobil.com/MarineLubes-En/Files/mobiltherm-600-Series-factsheet.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 08 2016)",
}

@misc{mobiltb,
author = {{M}obil {O}il {C}orporation},
title ="{T}echnical {B}ulletin {H}eating with {M}obiltherm",
note = "Reference JEB 782305",
Year ="1978",
}

@misc{moly,
author = {{B}elray Company},
title ="{B}llRay Molylube Extreme Pressure Grease",
Note ="http://www.belray.com/molylube-extreme-pressure-grease-ac-0",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{nbic,
author = {{N}orthern  {B}oard {I}nspection {C}ode},
title ="{T}hermal  {F}luid {H}eaters",
note = "NB23 2.2.12.7 Section 2 Pages 17-18",
Year ="2019",
}

@misc{parat,
author = {{P}aratherm},
title ="{TAN}(Neutralisation Number",
Note ="http://www.paratherm.com",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2021)",
}

@misc{perm,
Author = "{P}ermutit Company",
title ="Dearator Information",
note = "Permutit now Siemens Water Technologies",
year = "2000",
}

@misc{radcoblr,
Author ="{R}adco {B}oilers",
title = {General historical information Hot Oil Systems},
year ="1981"
}

@manual{radcoflx,
title = {Variable Pipe Supports PS001},
author ="{R}adcoflex {A}ustralia Pty Ltd",
year ="(accessed Sep 2016)",
note = "http://www.radcoflex.com.au/datasheets/ps001.pdf",
}

@misc{Rathi,
author = "{R}athi Couplings Australia",
title ="{R}athi Spacer Couplings",
Note ="http://www.rathicouplings.com/",
Year ="(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{rkc,
author = "{R}ika {K}ogyo Co. Ltd",
title ="{PID} {C}ontrol ",
note ="MD-51H, Pages 16-20",
year ="(circa 1985)",
}

@misc{shoils2,
author = "{S}hell {A}ustralia",
title ="{S}hell {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il {S}2",
Note ="http://s02.static-shell.com/content/dam/shell/static/ind/downloads/lubes-b2b/other-shell-lubricants/heat-transfer-oil.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{shoiltb,
author = "{{S}hell {A}ustralia}",
title ="{S}hell {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il {T}hermia {B}",
Note ="http://www.dayanoilco.com/upload/product/1451466936.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 26 2016)",
}

@misc{shtest,
author = "{S}hell {A}ustralia",
title ="{S}hell Heat Transfer Oil Analysis",
Note ="NRHLS Progressive Results",
Year ="2001",
}

@misc{Siem,
author = {{S}iemens Building Technologies},
title ="{S}iemens Burner Controls LFL1.",
Note ="http://www.allcontrols.com.au/pdf/LFL-Gas-Burner-Control2.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{siem2,
title ="{C}losed {L}oop {C}ontrol with {S}imatic {S}5",
author = "{S}iemens {AG}",
note ="Basic Concepts",
year ="1989",
}

@misc{sihimtn,
author = {{S}ihi Pumps},
title ="{M}aintenance of ZTN Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
Note ="http://www.ceienterprises.com/downloads/15-02-03.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{sihiztn,
author = {{S}ihi Pumps},
title ="{Z}TN Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
Note ="www.sihi-pumps.com",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{spirax,
author = {{S}pirax {S}arco},
title = "{C}atalogue {I}nformation",
address = "Forge Street Blactown NSW",
year = "(Catalogue accessed June 2016)",
note= {http://www.spiraxsarco.com/global/a}
}

@misc{uqdwg,
author = "{U}niquip {A}ustralia {P}ty {L}td",
Title ="Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd, Schematic Drawing S034-014C, Expansion System, June 2016",
year ="2016",
}

@misc{uqusg,
author = "{U}niquip {A}ustralia Pty Ltd",
title = {Unfired Steam Generator information},
year = "2016",
}

@misc{uts,
author ="{U}niversal {T}echnical {S}ervices",
title = "{TK} {S}olver computer program",
note="http://www.uts.com",
Year ="(accessed May 14, 2016)",
}

@misc{360water,
author = {{360} {W}ater {P}ty {L}td},
title ="{R}eliable {S}olutions for {W}ater {P}roblems",
note = "www.360water.com.au",
Year ="(accessed November 22 2016)",
}

@manual{wbs340362,
title ="{{C}haracteristic {C}urves for the valve range 340/342/346/347, P11}",
Author ="{B}alz and {S}ohn",
address ="Heilbronn, Germany",
year ="2003",
}

@misc{zph,
author ="{cibs} Journal",
title ="{Z}ero Pressure Header Circuits",
note = "Technical guide to low loss headers",
year = "2023"
}
```

I am also looking to reduce the space at the start of chapters.

Comment: For better readability this example could be shorter, formatted properly, and include more details.

Comment: There is a few things you can do: Start by posting a full MWE, i.e. a short program that compiles and shows your problem. Do some troubleshooting: Does this happen with a reduced bib file? If not, there's probably an error in there. You can also try cleaning up your Bibliography using a tool like https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy/index.html

Comment: In almost all entries, the author is "corporate". It is simply wrong to write `"{R}ika {K}ogyo Co. Ltd",`, as you're misleading BibTeX into believing that it's dealing with a person whose surname is "Ltd" and whose given names are "Rika", "Kogyo," and "Co.". Yikes! What you should be writing is `{{Rika Kogyo Co. Ltd}},`. Similarly, `author ="{A}utodesk Inc.",` should be `author ={{Autodesk Inc.}},`, `author = {{D}ow Chemical Company},` should be `author = {{Dow Chemical Company}},`, etc etc.

Comment: Your entries also contain quite a few factual errors. E.g., `author = "{F}oxboro {MA}, {USA}",` simply cannot be correct, as Foxboro is a town in Massachusetts, a state in the New England area of the US. Poor BibTeX has no choice but to think it's dealing with an author whose surname is "USA" and whose given names are "Foxboro" and "MA". In my view, the entry's actual author is *missing*, and the field should be `address = "Foxboro MA",`. (If readers can't figure out that "MA" stands for "Massachusetts", they need help of a far different kind.)

Comment: As we already told you, please add a minimal but complete example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/101651. Otherwise, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't give enough information to answer (at first you tagged your question with `biblatex` but, from the code you posted, you're not using it).

I tried the following minimal example, the error I got is a wrong format for a date `date ="April 89"` of the entry `fictrl` that should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

In general, your .bib file is badly formatted, see Mico's comment

> It is simply wrong to write `"{R}ika {K}ogyo Co. Ltd",`, as you're
> misleading BibTeX into believing that it's dealing with a person whose
> surname is "Ltd" and whose given names are "Rika", "Kogyo," and "Co.".
> Yikes! What you should be writing is `{{Rika Kogyo Co. Ltd}},`.
> Similarly, `author ="{A}utodesk Inc.",` should be `author ={{Autodesk Inc.}},`, `author = {{D}ow Chemical Company},` should be `author = {{Dow Chemical Company}},` etc etc

In the entry `al50`, `author = "{A}llweiler{AG}",` should be `author = {{A}llweiler {AG}},` and it's likely there are other errors I have no time to detect.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ab,
title ="{P}rocess Control Instruction PID",
author = "{A}lan {B}radley {USA}",
note ="Instruction Set Reference",
year ="(circa 1990)",
}

@manual{al50,
title ="{C}haract.curves {NTT} 50-160/01",
author = "{A}llweiler {AG}",
edition ="V2.06, Curve number 050 01160 0129",
note ="Aust Agent Pump Power Aust Pty Ltd, email Nov 14, 2014",
address ="Melbourne, Australia",
year ="2014",
}

@manual{al77,
title ="{V}olute {C}asing {C}entrifugal {P}umps {PN}16 for {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}ils up to 350 deg {C}",
Author ="{A}llweiler {AG}",
address ={Radolfzell, Germany},
edition ="VM 500 GB/09.04 Ident No. 795277",
year ="2009",
}

@misc{audesk,
author ="{A}utodesk Inc.",
title ="{A}utocad CAD Software",
Note ="http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad/overview",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{blzpid,
author = "{B}aelz {A}utomatic",
title ="{O}perating {I}nstructions",
note = "Model 6590",
Year ="2010",
}

@misc{caht12,
author = "{C}astrol",
title ="{P}erfecto HT12 {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il ",
Note ="http://yairerez.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/PERFECTO-HT.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{dowthm,
author = {{D}ow Chemical Company},
title ="{D}owtherm Heat Transfer Fluids",
Note ="http://www.dow.com/heattrans/products/synthetic/dowtherm.htm",
Year ="(accessed October 18 2016)",
}

@misc{eath66,
author = {{E}astman Chemical Company},
title ="{T}herminol 66 Heat Transfer Fluid",
Note ="https://www.therminol.com/products/Therminol-66",
Year ="(accessed October 12 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxbe,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{B}oiler {E}fficiency",
Year ="(accessed June 2016)",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com",
}

@misc{engtboxnpsh,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{Net} {P}ositive {S}uction {H}ead",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/npsh-net-positive-suction-head-d-634.html ",
Year ="(accessed Sep 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxpid,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontrol {T}erms",
note = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/process-control-terms-d-666.html",
Year ="(accessed Nov 2016)",
}

@misc{engtbox2,
author = {{E}ngineering {T}oolbox},
title ="{V}alves {F}low {C}haracteristics",
note ="https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/control-valves-flow-characteristics-d-485.html",
Year ="(accessed Oct 2021)",
}

@manual{fictrl,
author = "{F}isher {C}ontrols {I}nternalional {I}nc",
title ="{F}isher {S}izing {M}anual",
date={1989-04},
address ="USA",
year ="1989",
}

@misc{foxb,
title ="{I}ntroduction to {P}rocess {C}ontrol",
author = "{F}oxboro {MA}, {USA}",
note ="ITCG",
year ="(circa 1985)",
}

@misc{gkss,
author = "{GKSS Industrial Heating}",
title ="{G}KSS {I}ndustrial {H}eating, general information",
Note ="from {G}KSS now Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd",
Year ="2013",
}

@misc{hazardsxxI,
title ="{S}afety in Design of ThermalFluid Heat Transfer Systems",
author = {{T}ony {E}nnis},
note ="Symposium Series 155 Hazards XXI 2009 IChemE",
year ="2009",
}

@misc{hazardsxxII,
title ="{F}ire and explosion hazards with thermal fluid systems",
author = "{A}lisom McKay Projen plc UK  and {R}ichard Bradley Heat Transfer systems {UK}",
note ="Symposium Series 156 hazards XXII 2011 IChemE",
year ="2011",
}

@manual{heattl,
author = "{W}alter{W}agner",
title ="{H}eat {T}ransfer {T}echnique with {O}rganic {M}edia",
date ="3rd {E}dition, {D}ecember 1975",
address ="{S}chwetzingen {G}ermany",
year ="1977",
}

@misc{hwell,
author = "{H}oneywell",
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontroller {P}roduct {M}anual, {UDC3300}",
year ="(accessed November 16 2016)",
note = "https://www.honeywellprocess.com/library/support/Public/Documents/51-52-25-86.pdf",
}

@misc{idc,
author = "{I}ndustrial {D}ata {C}ommunications {P}ty {L}td",
title ="{P}rocess {C}ontrol {T}heory",
note ="2.01, Practical Process Control for Engineers and Technicians",
year ="1995",
}

@manual{kern,
title ="{P}rocess {H}eat {T}ransfer",
author ="{K}ern, D.Q.",
edition ="{I}nternational {S}tudent {E}dition",
note ="ISBN 0-07-Y85353-3",
address ="McGraw Hill, Singapore",
year ="1986",
}

@misc{kf21d,
author ="{K}laus Fischer",
title ="{D}ifferential Pressure Switch type 21D",
Note ="http://www.dartinstruments.com.au/images/transswi/fischer/DS21-english-alt.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{kopr,
author = "{J}etlube Co",
title ="{K}opr-Kote Anti Seize Compound",
Note ="http://www.jetlube.com/pdf/KOPR-KOTE-INDUSTRIAL-tds.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{mcad,
author = {{H}erne Software},
title ="{M}athcad",
Note ="www.hearne.software/mathcad",
Year ="(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{mobil600,
author = {{E}xon Mobil},
title ="{M}obiltherm 600 Series {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}ils",
Note ="https://lubes.exxonmobil.com/MarineLubes-En/Files/mobiltherm-600-Series-factsheet.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 08 2016)",
}

@misc{mobiltb,
author = {{M}obil {O}il {C}orporation},
title ="{T}echnical {B}ulletin {H}eating with {M}obiltherm",
note = "Reference JEB 782305",
Year ="1978",
}

@misc{moly,
author = {{B}elray Company},
title ="{B}llRay Molylube Extreme Pressure Grease",
Note ="http://www.belray.com/molylube-extreme-pressure-grease-ac-0",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{nbic,
author = {{N}orthern  {B}oard {I}nspection {C}ode},
title ="{T}hermal  {F}luid {H}eaters",
note = "NB23 2.2.12.7 Section 2 Pages 17-18",
Year ="2019",
}

@misc{parat,
author = {{P}aratherm},
title ="{TAN}(Neutralisation Number",
Note ="http://www.paratherm.com",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2021)",
}

@misc{perm,
Author = "{P}ermutit Company",
title ="Dearator Information",
note = "Permutit now Siemens Water Technologies",
year = "2000",
}

@misc{radcoblr,
Author ="{R}adco {B}oilers",
title = {General historical information Hot Oil Systems},
year ="1981"
}

@manual{radcoflx,
title = {Variable Pipe Supports PS001},
author ="{R}adcoflex {A}ustralia Pty Ltd",
year ="(accessed Sep 2016)",
note = "http://www.radcoflex.com.au/datasheets/ps001.pdf",
}

@misc{Rathi,
author = "{R}athi Couplings Australia",
title ="{R}athi Spacer Couplings",
Note ="http://www.rathicouplings.com/",
Year ="(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{rkc,
author = "{R}ika {K}ogyo Co. Ltd",
title ="{PID} {C}ontrol ",
note ="MD-51H, Pages 16-20",
year ="(circa 1985)",
}

@misc{shoils2,
author = "{S}hell {A}ustralia",
title ="{S}hell {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il {S}2",
Note ="http://s02.static-shell.com/content/dam/shell/static/ind/downloads/lubes-b2b/other-shell-lubricants/heat-transfer-oil.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{shoiltb,
author = "{{S}hell {A}ustralia}",
title ="{S}hell {H}eat {T}ransfer {O}il {T}hermia {B}",
Note ="http://www.dayanoilco.com/upload/product/1451466936.pdf",
Year ="(accessed Sep 26 2016)",
}

@misc{shtest,
author = "{S}hell {A}ustralia",
title ="{S}hell Heat Transfer Oil Analysis",
Note ="NRHLS Progressive Results",
Year ="2001",
}

@misc{Siem,
author = {{S}iemens Building Technologies},
title ="{S}iemens Burner Controls LFL1.",
Note ="http://www.allcontrols.com.au/pdf/LFL-Gas-Burner-Control2.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{siem2,
title ="{C}losed {L}oop {C}ontrol with {S}imatic {S}5",
author = "{S}iemens {AG}",
note ="Basic Concepts",
year ="1989",
}

@misc{sihimtn,
author = {{S}ihi Pumps},
title ="{M}aintenance of ZTN Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
Note ="http://www.ceienterprises.com/downloads/15-02-03.pdf",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{sihiztn,
author = {{S}ihi Pumps},
title ="{Z}TN Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
Note ="www.sihi-pumps.com",
Year ="(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{spirax,
author = {{S}pirax {S}arco},
title = "{C}atalogue {I}nformation",
address = "Forge Street Blactown NSW",
year = "(Catalogue accessed June 2016)",
note= {http://www.spiraxsarco.com/global/a}
}

@misc{uqdwg,
author = "{U}niquip {A}ustralia {P}ty {L}td",
Title ="Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd, Schematic Drawing S034-014C, Expansion System, June 2016",
year ="2016",
}

@misc{uqusg,
author = "{U}niquip {A}ustralia Pty Ltd",
title = {Unfired Steam Generator information},
year = "2016",
}

@misc{uts,
author ="{U}niversal {T}echnical {S}ervices",
title = "{TK} {S}olver computer program",
note="http://www.uts.com",
Year ="(accessed May 14, 2016)",
}

@misc{360water,
author = {{360} {W}ater {P}ty {L}td},
title ="{R}eliable {S}olutions for {W}ater {P}roblems",
note = "www.360water.com.au",
Year ="(accessed November 22 2016)",
}

@manual{wbs340362,
title ="{{C}haracteristic {C}urves for the valve range 340/342/346/347, P11}",
Author ="{B}alz and {S}ohn",
address ="Heilbronn, Germany",
year ="2003",
}

@misc{zph,
author ="{cibs} Journal",
title ="{Z}ero Pressure Header Circuits",
note = "Technical guide to low loss headers",
year = "2023"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
    
\end{document}
```

Regarding the second question (to reduce the space at the start of chapters) you gave not enough information to answer. Which `documentclass` are you using? Please add a complete minimal example (like the one I posted) to your question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Issue resolved by using an earlier program with the modified bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there's no way to sugarcoat the bad news: There are many errors and inaccuracies in your bib file. Among them are

- Failure to identify "corporate" authors as such. It is simply wrong to write `author="{R}ika {K}ogyo Co. Ltd"`, as you're misleading BibTeX into believing that it's dealing with a person whose surname is "Ltd" and whose given names are "Rika", "Kogyo," and "Co.". Yikes! What you should be writing is `author={{Rika Kogyo Co. Ltd}},`. Similarly, `author ="{A}utodesk Inc."` should be `author ={{Autodesk Inc.}}`, `author = {{D}ow Chemical Company}` should be `author = {{Dow Chemical Company}}`, etc etc.
- `author = "{F}oxboro {MA}, {USA}"` simply cannot be correct, as Foxboro is a town in Massachusetts, which is a state in the New England area of the US. Poor BibTeX has no choice but to think it's dealing with an author whose surname is "USA" and whose given names are "Foxboro" and "MA". In my view, the entry's actual author is *missing* and the field should be address = "Foxboro MA",. (If readers can't figure out that "MA" stands for "Massachusetts", they need help of a far different kind...)
- Another case of information (likely) being faulty concerns the two entries authored by `{{Allweiler AG}}`, which is an example of a "corporate" author. Did this company really move from Radolfzell, Germany to Melbourne, Australia between 2009 and 2014? I suppose it's *not entirely impossible* that they made such a long-distance move. However, I do harbor some doubts that this is indeed the case.
- By the way, I've heard of a company called `Allen-Bradley` (yes, with a hyphenation character in its name; moreover, they are based in the US), but not of one called `Alan Bradley USA`, in the field of interest to the bib instruction.
- Because you've chosen to employ the almost prehistorically-ancient `plain` bibliography style, you can't process URL strings properly. I suggest you switch to the much newer `plainnat` bibliography style and change many of the `note` field names to `url`. In the entries affected by this change, you'll also need to change the `year` field to `note`. I further recommend you load the `xurl` package so that long URL strings may be line-broken *anywhere*.
- A number of URL strings no longer seem to be valid. E.g., `http://www.360water.com.au/`.  The fact that this URL may have been valid when you last visited this site, way back in November 2016, isn't much of an excuse, is it? You owe it to your readers to ensure that the information in the URL strings is still valid. If you know the URL string is invalid at this point in time and you simply can't come up with something that is up to date, please just don't show the invalid URL string.
- By my count, 27 of the 48 entries don't have a `year` field. This leads to BibTeX issuing 27 warning (not error) messages. Do please try to supply the missing `year` information.
- Some entries have a field called `date` instead of `year`. Unfortunately, BibTeX -- unlike biblatex/biber -- doesn't recognize a field called `date`. In those cases, it's necessary to manually edit the entries to allocate the information contained in the `date` field to new fields (generally `year` and `month`).

Once you've fixed these issues -- which I really think you owe to your readers... -- the error message you report in your query goes away by itself.

Making the recommended changes (minus the one about switching from `plain` to `plainnat`) will also be useful if you choose to employ biblatex/biber instead of natbib/plainnat.

The following screenshot shows the first 5 of the 48 entries in total.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}

@misc{ab,
title  = "Process Control Instruction {PID}",
author = {{Alan Bradley USA}},
note   = "Instruction Set Reference, (circa 1990)",
}

@manual{al50,
title   = "Charact.curves {NTT} 50-160/01",
author  = {{Allweiler AG}},
edition = "V2.06, {Curve} number 050 01160 0129",
note    = "Aust Agent Pump Power Aust Pty Ltd, email Nov 14, 2014",
address = "Melbourne, Australia",
year    = "2014",
}

@manual{al77,
title   = "Volute Casing Centrifugal Pumps {PN16} for Heat Transfer Oils up to 350 deg~{C}",
Author  = {{Allweiler AG}},
address = {Radolfzell, Germany},
edition = "VM 500 GB/09.04 Ident No. 795277",
year    = "2009",
}

@misc{audesk,
author = {{Autodesk Inc.}},
title  = "Autocad {CAD} Software",
url    = "http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad/overview",
note   = "(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{blzpid,
author = {{Baelz Automatic}},
title  = "Operating Instructions",
note   = "Model 6590",
Year   = "2010",
}

@misc{caht12,
author = "Castrol",
title  = "Perfecto {HT12} Heat Transfer Oil ",
url    = "http://yairerez.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/PERFECTO-HT.pdf",
note   = "(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{dowthm,
author = {{Dow Chemical Company}},
title  = "Dowtherm Heat Transfer Fluids",
url    = "http://www.dow.com/heattrans/products/synthetic/dowtherm.htm",
note   = "(accessed October 18 2016)",
}

@misc{eath66,
author = {{Eastman Chemical Company}},
title  = "Therminol 66 Heat Transfer Fluid",
url    = "https://www.therminol.com/products/Therminol-66",
note   = "(accessed October 12 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxbe,
author = {{Engineering Toolbox}},
title  = "Boiler Efficiency",
note   = "(accessed June 2016)",
url    = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com",
}

@misc{engtboxnpsh,
author = {{Engineering Toolbox}},
title  = "Net Positive Suction Head",
url    = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/npsh-net-positive-suction-head-d-634.html",
note   ="(accessed Sep 2016)",
}

@misc{engtboxpid,
author = {{Engineering Toolbox}},
title  = "Process Control Terms",
url    = "http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/process-control-terms-d-666.html",
note   = "(accessed Nov 2016)",
}

@misc{engtbox2,
author = {{Engineering Toolbox}},
title  = "Valves Flow Characteristics",
url    = "https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/control-valves-flow-characteristics-d-485.html",
note   = "(accessed Oct 2021)",
}

@manual{fictrl,
author = {{Fisher Controls Internalional Inc}},
title  = "Fisher Sizing Manual",
year   = 1989,
month  = apr,
address= "USA",
year   = "1989",
}
%date ="April 89",

@misc{foxb,
title   = "Introduction to Process Control",
author  = "Anon.",
howpublished = "Foxboro MA, USA",
note    = "ITCG, (circa 1985)",
}
% author field was missing

@misc{gkss,
author = {{GKSS Industrial Heating}},
title  = "{GKSS} Industrial Heating, general information",
Note   = "From {GKSS}, now Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd",
Year   = "2013",
}

@misc{hazardsxxI,
title  = "Safety in Design of ThermalFluid Heat Transfer Systems",
author = "Tony Ennis",
note   = "Symposium Series 155 Hazards XXI 2009 IChemE",
year   = "2009",
}

@misc{hazardsxxII,
title  = "Fire and explosion hazards with thermal fluid systems",
author = {{Alisom McKay Projen plc, UK} and {Richard Bradley Heat Transfer systems, UK}},
note   = "Symposium Series 156 hazards XXII 2011 IChemE",
year   = "2011",
}

@manual{heattl,
author = "Walter Wagner",
title  = "Heat Transfer Technique with Organic Media",
year   = 1975,
month  = dec,
edition= "3rd",
address="Schwetzingen, Germany",
}
%year ="1977",
%date ="3rd {E}dition, {D}ecember 1975",

@misc{hwell,
author = "Honeywell",
title  = "Process Controller Product Manual, {UDC3300}",
note   = "(accessed November 16 2016)",
url    = "https://www.honeywellprocess.com/library/support/Public/Documents/51-52-25-86.pdf",
}

@misc{idc,
author = {{Industrial Data Communications Pty Ltd}},
title  = "{P}rocess {C}ontrol {T}heory",
note   = "2.01, Practical Process Control for Engineers and Technicians",
year   = "1995",
}

@manual{kern,
title  = "Process Heat Transfer",
author = "Kern, D. Q.",
edition= "International Student Edition",
isbn   = "0-07-Y85353-3",
addres = "McGraw Hill, Singapore",
year   = "1986",
}

@misc{kf21d,
author = "Klaus Fischer",
title  = "Differential Pressure Switch type {21D}",
url    = "http://www.dartinstruments.com.au/images/transswi/fischer/DS21-english-alt.pdf",
note   = "(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{kopr,
author = {{Jetlube Co}},
title  = "{Kopr-Kote} Anti Seize Compound",
url    = "http://www.jetlube.com/pdf/KOPR-KOTE-INDUSTRIAL-tds.pdf",
note   = "(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{mcad,
author = {{Herne Software}},
title  = "Mathcad",
url    = "www.hearne.software/mathcad",
note   = "(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{mobil600,
author = {{Exxon Mobil}},
title  = "Mobiltherm 600 Series Heat Transfer Oils",
url    = "https://lubes.exxonmobil.com/MarineLubes-En/Files/mobiltherm-600-Series-factsheet.pdf",
note   = "(accessed October 08 2016)",
}

@misc{mobiltb,
author = {{Mobil Oil Corporation}},
title  = "Technical Bulletin, {Heating} with {Mobiltherm}",
note   = "Reference JEB 782305",
Year   = "1978",
}

@misc{moly,
author = {{Belray Company}},
title  = "BellRay Molylube Extreme Pressure Grease",
url    = "http://www.belray.com/molylube-extreme-pressure-grease-ac-0",
note   = "(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{nbic,
author = {{Northern Board Inspection Code}},
title  = "Thermal Fluid Heaters",
note   = "NB23 2.2.12.7 Section~2, Pages 17--18",
Year   = "2019",
}

@misc{parat,
author = {Paratherm},
title  = "{TAN} (Neutralisation Number)",
url    = "http://www.paratherm.com",
note   = "(accessed October 21 2021)",
}

@misc{perm,
Author = {{Permutit Company}},
title  = "Dearator Information",
note   = "Permutit now Siemens Water Technologies",
year   = "2000",
}

@misc{radcoblr,
Author = {{Radco Boilers}},
title  = {General historical information Hot Oil Systems},
year   = "1981",
}

@manual{radcoflx,
title  = {Variable Pipe Supports PS001},
author = {{Radcoflex Australia Pty Ltd}},
note   = "(accessed Sep 2016)",
url    = "http://www.radcoflex.com.au/datasheets/ps001.pdf",
}

@misc{Rathi,
author = {{Rathi Couplings Australia}},
title  = "Rathi Spacer Couplings",
url    = "http://www.rathicouplings.com/",
note   = "(accessed November 12 2016)",
}

@misc{rkc,
author = {{Rika Kogyo Co. Ltd}},
title  = "{PID} Control",
note   = "MD-51H, Pages 16--20",
year   = "(circa 1985)",
}

@misc{shoils2,
author = {{Shell Australia}},
title  = "Shell Heat Transfer Oil {S2}",
url    = "http://s02.static-shell.com/content/dam/shell/static/ind/downloads/lubes-b2b/other-shell-lubricants/heat-transfer-oil.pdf",
note   = "(accessed Sep 27 2016)",
}

@misc{shoiltb,
author = {{Shell Australia}},
title  = "Shell Heat Transfer Oil Thermia {B}",
url    = "http://www.dayanoilco.com/upload/product/1451466936.pdf",
note   = "(accessed Sep 26 2016)",
}

@misc{shtest,
author = {{Shell Australia}},
title  = "Shell Heat Transfer Oil Analysis",
Note   = "NRHLS Progressive Results",
Year   = "2001",
}

@misc{Siem,
author = {{Siemens Building Technologies}},
title  = "Siemens Burner Controls {LFL1}",
url    = "http://www.allcontrols.com.au/pdf/LFL-Gas-Burner-Control2.pdf",
note   = "(accessed October 21 2016)",
}

@misc{siem2,
title  = "Closed Loop Control with {Simatic S5}",
author = {{Siemens AG}},
note   = "Basic Concepts",
year   = "1989",
}

@misc{sihimtn,
author = {{Sihi Pumps}},
title  = "Maintenance of {ZTN} Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
url    = "http://www.ceienterprises.com/downloads/15-02-03.pdf",
note   = "(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{sihiztn,
author = {{Sihi Pumps}},
title  = "{ZTN} Series Heat Transfer Oil Pumps",
url    = "www.sihi-pumps.com",
note   = "(accessed October 14 2016)",
}

@misc{spirax,
author = {{Spirax Sarco}},
title  = "Catalogue Information",
howpublished = "Forge Street Blactown NSW",
note   = "(Catalogue accessed June 2016)",
url    = {http://www.spiraxsarco.com/global/a}
}

@misc{uqdwg,
author = {{Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd}},
Title  = "Schematic Drawing {S034-014C}, Expansion System, June 2016",
year   = "2016",
}

@misc{uqusg,
author = {{Uniquip Australia Pty Ltd}},
title  = {Unfired Steam Generator information},
year   = "2016",
}

@misc{uts,
author = {{Universal Technical Services}},
title  = "{TK} Solver computer program",
url    = "http://www.uts.com",
note   = "(accessed May 14, 2016)",
}

@misc{360water,
author = {{360 Water Pty Ltd}},
title  = "Reliable Solutions for Water Problems",
url    = "www.360water.com.au",
note   = "(accessed November 22 2016)",
}

@manual{wbs340362,
title  = "Characteristic Curves for the valve range 340/342/346/347, {P11}",
Author = {{Balz und Sohn}},
address= "Heilbronn, Germany",
year   = "2003",
}

@misc{zph,
author = {{Cibs Journal}},
title  = "Zero Pressure Header Circuits",
note   = "Technical guide to low loss headers",
year   = "2023",
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks in URL strings at arbitrary locations
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % create numeric-style citation call-outs
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Issue resolved by using earlier program with modified bibliography.